# How do I close a question?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close

I would like to close a question in order to make clear that it does not need any further answers. Where can I find information on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting to close is considered a [privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) which is attained at 3,000 reputation. Before this milestone, your only option to initiate this would be to flag a question for moderator attention and requestion closure (another [privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) requiring only 15 reputation):

[image]

(Note that you may not see the `close` option in the above image.)

The above is the appropriate way to handle this situation. It keeps the question within the network (so it will be visible for future visitors) and may help others. However, if it would be of no help to anyone - discretion applies here - you can also delete it (every user can post and delete their own posts). A similar `delete` option would be visible for owners of a post.

If a question is closed (for whatever reason) and it doesn't have much *traction* (loosely defined), [it may eventually be deleted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).

Some related resources on the [StackExchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com):

- [Etiquette for closing your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5215/168244)
- [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/168244)
- [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/168244)

Comment: Might be worth adding that 'closing to make it clear does not need further answers' doesn't really fit the SE model: questions/answers shouldn't _just_ be for the OP and 'answered' is different to 'closed'.